# How to switch between low-level math libraries linked to in scientific computing packages used in MATLAB/Python, on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, matlab, intel-mkl, amd-processor

I have an AMD Ryzen 9 5900 cpu running on a Windows 10 build. Partly because of the [known issues with Intel's MKL running on AMD CPUs](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/f2pbvz/discussion_workaround_for_mkl_on_amd/), and partly because I just want to try out AMD's Optimizing CPU Libraries ([AOCL](https://developer.amd.com/amd-aocl/)), I'm looking to install AOCL and do some benchmarking to see how much performance changes on my build for some matlab and python (numpy and scipy) functions.

AMD has simple instructions on how to install the AOCL binaries on Windows, but I couldn't find a more detailed explanation of how to changes the paths to allow functions in higher-level programming languages (e.g. matlab and python) to link to AOCL over MKL (and whatever other OME defaults).

Are there, for example, settings in MATLAB that a user can change to specify which lower-level math libraries to use? Similarly, for python packages, how can I specify which lower-level math libraries the package uses (I am using conda as my python env and package manager, but is there a general way to do this, or only python distribution and package manager specific)?

TLDR; I want to be able to switch between which lower-level libraries are linked to at runtime - is this possible and does anyone know how to do so?

Comment: There is a [User Guide](https://developer.amd.com/wp-content/resources/57404_AOCL_UG_Rev_3.1.pdf) accompanying the math lib. You should refer to that for various path of code integration.

Comment: Hi yes, I saw that User Guide. It has detailed instructions on installation for GNU/Linux machines particularly for each individual library in AOCL from source and how to set the install paths, and the Window section is very brief, basically just says run this .exe, but the guide doesn't really answer my question (which ofc is reasonable, I consider it outside the scope of what I'd expect AMD to provide)

Comment: Oh, I don't believe there's a ready made OS command like "set MATHLIB=AMD" sort of thing. The libraries must be referenced during compile time. For DLLs sharing identical APIs, it may be switchable with some path and filename hacks. Otherwise recompile is the easiest way (instead of in-memory disassembly etc.).

Comment: I see, thanks, so I guess for what I want to do in terms of benchmarking, I should find a way to compile matlab and numpy and scipy both with mkl and with aocl (in particular blis), and then benchmark each separately? If you think that's the best approach feel free to write an answer!

Comment: By the way, in this comment on this mathworks post: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/396296-what-if-anything-can-be-done-to-optimize-performance-for-modern-amd-cpu-s#comment_773706

it is written "it is possible to substitute a different BLAS implementation for the BLAS qualified by MathWorks for use in MATLAB. This can be done by specifying the full path to the .so/.dll containing your BLAS implementation in an environment variable called BLAS_VERSION"

This sounds like the low-level libs are picked up at runtime, and so matlab doesn't need to be recompiled against each?

Comment: Right, the MATLAB BLAS implementation is basically a path/file hack officially documented, by referencing the library indirectly during compile time using an environment variable, which is quite thoughtful. It's indeed possible to replace other well-defined DLL/so files with compatible alternative library. But it's gonna to be application/library/file specific, and more likely than not, undocumented.